# Is there something like "global::" for VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, types, identifier

I am writing a code-generator that will need to output some miniscule portions of VB.NET code, and since this is a code generator that will add user-provider code, I'd like to try to avoid type name conflicts with types or names in the user-provided code.

In C#, I can prefix types with `global::` to make sure they're matched from the global type namespace hierarchy, rather than some local name, but is there a similar system for VB.NET?

ie. this:

```
global::System.String
```

Comment: The final method, if anyone is interested, can be found here: http://texttemplate.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/3dd6ee364cde#TextTemplate%2fTypeHelper.cs

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's simply the [`Global` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt9tafza.aspx):

```
Dim n As Global.System.Int32
```

Answer (score 7):

My VB is very rusty, and I don't have a compiler in front of me... But isn't it just

```
Global.System.String
```

? Let me know if I've dreamt this, and I'll delete...

Comment: No, you definitely didn't dream it, it worked nicely, but I accepted @Oded's answer, since his says "this is it" and yours says "I think this is it" :)